# mouseClicked not working with if statement to call a function

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm currently learning how to code javascript on khan academy. I'm working on the `fish tank project`.

**Code**:

```
 background(89, 216, 255);

var centerX ;
var centerY ;
var bodyLength = 118;
var bodyHeight = 74;

var drawFish = function(centerX, centerY) {
noStroke();
fill (random(1,255), random(1,255), random(1,255));
// body
ellipse(centerX, centerY, bodyLength, bodyHeight);
// tail
var tailWidth = bodyLength/4;
var tailHeight = bodyHeight/2;
triangle(centerX-bodyLength/2, centerY,
         centerX-bodyLength/2-tailWidth, centerY-tailHeight,
         centerX-bodyLength/2-tailWidth, centerY+tailHeight);
// eye
fill(33, 33, 33);
ellipse(centerX+bodyLength/4, centerY, bodyHeight/5, bodyHeight/5);
};

if(mouseClicked) {
  drawFish(random(1,400), random(1,400)); } else { text ("Left click to add fish!", 100, 100); }
```

It works if I just call the functions many times with copy and paste but I want it to work if I clicked on the screen. I have tried it also with `mousePressed` and `mouseIsPressed`.

Comment: what is "mouseClicked"??? where you are setting it???... may be is useful seeing your complete code

Comment: CODE: mouseClicked = function() {
    drawFish(random(1,400), random(1,400));};                                  That works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mouseClicked` seems nothing in your code. Use `onClick` rather. For example:

```
var element = document.getElementById("id");
element.onclick = function() {
       drawFish(random(1,400), random(1,400)); 
}
```

Or, for simply clicking on document(or call page), use:

```
document.onclick = function() {
           drawFish(random(1,400), random(1,400)); 
    }
```

Comment: mouseClicked is something the website khanacademy added... Im not sure what exactly it is.

Comment: they might be setting its value somewhere, don't worry, try replace `if(mouseclicked).....else...` with the code i've written and check, it'll hopefully work.

Answer (score 0):

```
mouseClicked = function() {
    drawFish(random(1,400), random(1,400));};
```

If i use that code it seems to work. Does anyone know how I could use that but only have it create a new fish if i have mouseX and mouseY on a certain position?

Comment: Or how could i make it so when there's 10 fish it restarts and there's no fish?

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this after a few tries:

```
var drawBubble = function () {

    var bubbleX = (mouseX);
    var bubbleY = (mouseY);
    stroke(255, 255, 255);
    noFill();
    ellipse (bubbleX,bubbleY,20,20);
    fill(250, 250, 250);
    ellipse (bubbleX + 5, bubbleY - 2, 5,5);
};

var mouseClicked = function(){
  drawBubble (mouseX,mouseY);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

In javascript mouseevents are dictated by specifying the HTML area or object you want to act on. If you want to draw the fish on the screen, you can do

```
document.getElementById('body').onclick = function() {
    drawFish(...) //with your random place
}
```

The 'body' part could change depending on where you want mouseclick event to be valid. I'm assuming this project works with html so the  tag should work fine. But you can also do

```
document.onclick = function() {

}
```

as a global event handler

I'm not sure what mouseClicked is, but you want the draw method to trigger ON a mouseclick. So if your mouseClicked variable is changing dynamically in some other method, you should post that code as well.